# How to select a specific col + row from a table created in a FOR loop

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a table which I can input various types of data. 
I've created a table in JavaScript using a FOR loop:

```js
document.write("<table border=1>");
for (row=1; row<=4; row++) {
  document.write("<tr>");
  for (col=1; col<=5; col++) {
    document.write("<td>R" + row + "<br>C" + col + "</td>");

  }
  document.write("</tr>");
}
document.write("</table>");
```

This creates a 4x5 table, each including their respective row number(R) and column number(C).

Is there any way to specifically target one of the boxes within the table to input data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *Is there any way to specifically target one of the boxes within the table to input data?*

Yes, but let's back up a bit first. [`document.write()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/write) is an ancient way to build-up content on a web page and really only has very limited use cases today. The problems with it include the fact that if you use it in the wrong place, you can overwrite the existing page and the fact that it requires you to build up strings of content, which can be tedious with all the quoting and concatenation you wind up needing.

Instead, you should use the [Document Object Model](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model) to create elements in memory, configure them, and then "inject" them into some spot on the page. Additionally, there is a [specific API for working with tables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableElement), in particular and so you really should be using that:

```js
// This function can be called anytime you want a new table
function makeTable(rows, columns, target){
  // Create a new table element in memory (not on the page yet)
  let tbl = document.createElement("table");
  
  // Set up a loop to create the correct # of rows
  for(let r = 0; r < rows; r++){
    let newRow = tbl.insertRow();  // Create a new row in the table
    
    // Now set up a loop to create the correct # of columns in the  row
    for(let c = 0; c < columns; c++){
      let newCell = newRow.insertCell();  // Create new cell
      newCell.textContent = "Row " + (r + 1) + " - Cell " + (c + 1); // populate
    }
  }
  // Add the new table as a child of the referenced, pre-existing element on the page
  target.appendChild(tbl); 
  return tbl; // return a reference to the new table
}

// ************************************************
// Now, to actually make and interact with the table(s)

// Get a reference to the target elements that will hold the tables
let target1 = document.getElementById("target1");
let target2 = document.getElementById("target1");

// Call the function with the proper arguments:
let newTable1 = makeTable(5,4, target1);  // Make a 5 x 4 table in the first div
let newTable2 = makeTable(3,3, target2);  // Make a 3 x 3 table in the second div

// Now, you can target any cell you'd like by using indexes:
let cellToModify1 = newTable1.rows[3].cells[2];
cellToModify1.textContent = "OVERRIDDEN!";
cellToModify1.classList.add("updated");

let cellToModify2 = newTable2.rows[0].cells[2];
cellToModify2.textContent = "OVERRIDDEN!";
cellToModify2.classList.add("updated");
```

```css
table { border:2px solid red; margin:5px 0; }
td { border:1px dashed #d0d0d0; padding:3px; }
.updated { background-color:yellow; }
```

```html
<div id="target1"></div>
<div id="target2"></div>
```